# How to generate google Play App Signing in expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

google play will start app bundle format in August. Because I used the APK format before, I need to join Play App Signing at this time. How should I generate keys for the existing Expo program?

The following is the option to join Play App Signing, which one should I choose?
[image]

1. Export and upload the key from Android Studio
2. Export and upload the key from the Java keystore
3. Export and upload the key (do not use the Java keystore)

I read the official document, but I am still very confused and don’t know how to operate it. Can you tell me about the operation process? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this [documentation](https://www.robincussol.com/build-standalone-expo-apk-ipa-with-turtle-cli/) for generate apk for android.

I hope it can help you to generate android apk in expo.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, there are related questions I asked, and partners who have the same doubts can go in and read the article.

Comment: I don't think this answer is sufficient as the original question asked about aab format and not apk format.